# configuring a DPDT switch to choose between two RF signals

Tags: rf, switches, antenna, dpdt

I have 2 different signals coming in  I wanted to be able to switch between them (choose what to transmit) using a simple DPDT switch. I have the following configuration, but I feel like I'm missing something in my schematic.

Comment: The schematic shows two antennas, but your description suggests only one.  Can you update the description to be clear on (1) where the signals are coming from (2) where they are going (3) how many each of source and sink you have (4) if any signals are differential

Comment: With the circuit shown you basically have two separate (but linked) on-off controls (sig 1 -> ant 1  and sig  -> ant 2)

Comment: the signals are coming from an RF splitter. They're going to 2 different antennas.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're getting at here.  What do you want to switch between?  Are you trying to switch between s1 to a1/s2 to a2 vs. both disconnected (as drawn) or s1 to a1/s2 to a2 vs. s1 to a2/s2 to a1 or something else?

Comment: Hint: move Antenna 1 from B1 to B3.

Comment: Right now you have both being on at one time, then both off. You need to move one of the antennas to the 3rd pin (for example Antenna 1 to B3 as DoxyLover said)

Comment: @I.Wolfe do I have to add power to it from anywhere?

Comment: It should be fine if you just move that antenna line. With the switch in one position, signal 1 will be connected to antenna 1 while signal 2 is disconnected. Press the switch and signal 1 will disconnect while signal 2 will connect to antenna 2. Should be what you wanted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your text I understand that you have two signals which you want to switch between for broadcasting. As in: Two inputs(signals)/One output(antenna).
The DPDT switch you're using has two outputs. 
You might be looking for a SPDT switch.

Please give us more background information, like the type of signals and frequency of these signals.

As for the *simple* DPDT switch. You might be able to pull this off if it's a simple hobby project and the frequencies stay in the MF band or lower. For everything else, please don't do this. It probably adds a lot of parasitic capacitance and inductance to the signal path which won't help if you want a nice power transfer. RF is a delicate and very precise field where every parasitic property matters.

But there are options, there are dedicated RF switches out there and you might also find DIY schematics on the internet.

Comment: Sorry. I have two inputs and two outputs (two antennas) and I'm trying to use the switch to toggle between them.

Comment: Also if you know a good RF switch, please let me know.

Comment: And lastly, it's not MF, it's UHF.

Comment: This is still unclear, you want to choose/toggle between signals? Do you mean like: IN1->OU1, IN2->OU2 //(SWITCH)// IN1->OU2, IN2->OU1? I can't give you any information about a good RF switch, since I don't know anything about the signals you're broadcasting, the transmitter and the antenna. Even if I would know, this is still a too broad question to answer.

Comment: what i want to do is to keep one on while the other is off and vice versa.

Comment: If that's the case I assume that we're dealing with one antenna and two inputs. Since you don't want Signal 1 to be transmitting if Signal 2 is on. Another thing I could derive from your explanation is two signals at different frequencies which need different antenna's and don't transmit simultaneously. But please be more clear, also state information about the signals you want to transmit in your original post. We simply can't help very efficient this way.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use a *transfer switch*.

A transfer switch has 4 ports, which I'll call P1, P2, P3, and P4. In one state, P1 connects to P2 and P3 connects to P4. In the other state, P1 connects to P3 and P2 connects to P4.

In your situation, you'd connect source 1 to P1, source 2 to P4, antenna 1 to P2, and antenna 2 to P3. Then your two states would be

1. S1 -> A1 and S2 -> A2
2. S1 -> A2 and S2 -> A1

An example of a transfer switch, which might be overkill for your application, is Minicircuits [MTS-18-12B+](http://www.minicircuits.com/pdfs/MTS-18-12B+.pdf). For lower frequencies, it's also possible to construct a transfer switch from two SPDT switches.

Comment: what i want to do is to keep one on while the other is off and vice versa.

Comment: @JACK, you should edit your question to make it clear.